# HTML5 form validation pattern for letter with dot (.)

Tags: html, validation

How to write Html 5 Validation pattern for letter with dot (.)

For Ex :

Karthik.V

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you mean?

```html
<form onsubmit="return false">
  <input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+">
</form>
```